# If two lists are the same, do they coincide?

Tags: comparisons

Let's say our science group at the university has computed a list of values, like e.g. the masses of all the planets in the solar system. Some other group abroad computed the same list and got exactly the same values.

Do we say that our lists coincide? (which sounds to me like there was some chance or luck involved)

Or do they match?

?

[Edit:] If questions of this type are "off-topic", then the whole forum here is for highly academic purposes only, i.e. useless for 99.9 percent of people.

Comment: Yes, they *coincide* or even *agree*; there isn't necessarily any connotation of *coincidence* when you use the verb *coincide*.

Comment: "Coincide", when used in a scientific sense, means whatever that branch of science says it means.

Comment: If questions of this type are "off-topic", then the whole forum here is for highly academic purposes only, i.e. useless for 99.9 percent of people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the verb *[coincide](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coincide)* works here.

> 2.
>   to correspond exactly, as in nature, character, etc.:
>   His vocation coincides with his avocation.
>   3.
>   to agree or concur, as in thought or opinion:
>   Their opinions always coincide.

Synonyms include *match*, *agree* and *tally*.

*[Coincidence](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/coincidence?s=t)* is a noun to describe an event where things *coincide*, and is often used to connote an element of surprise (but not necessarily).